# Steering wheel vibration at 60+ MPH

Tags: tires, wheels, steering, vibration

I recently purchased a new set of tires for my 2007 Frontier.  Capitol Precision Trac are the make.  Before I replaced the worn tires my truck never shook and was always smooth no matter the speed.  Now even after having the tires balanced upon installation and a 4 wheel alignment my truck shakes at speeds over 60 MPH. I took it back to the place that put on my tires and had them recheck the balance of the tires and they said that they were good. I had BF Goodrich A/T on prior to these.  What could still be causing this issue?  Or is it the brand of tire I chose?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just put that same brand of tyres on my 4WD and I also have bad vibration over about 50km It must be the tread pattern.
It feels like you are driving over corrigations

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though one of your tires may have a slipped belt. This is pretty hard to diagnose because there isn't any real physical manifestation of it except for one of more of your tires being out of round. I don't believe this shows up when doing the balancing because it's more of a rolling thing. You can, however, rotate the tires front to back and see if the vibrations follows (if you can tell). From there, you'd need to localize it to left or right. Then get the tire company to buy off on it. You should not have been suffering this long with the tires.

As far as the brand of tires, it seems they have a fairly decent reputation. There was a recall on about 95,000 tires, but these were ones produced in 2009-2010, so I doubt you'd have these. You could check on [here](http://www.tirebusiness.com/article/20141126/NEWS/141129903) for information on the recall to see if they match yours.

Comment: Not heard of the belts slipping before. And good point re rotating the tyres to locate the issue

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the holes into which the wheel nuts fit are elongated, allowing the wheels to be off-centre ?

Or ( dare I say it ) that the wheel nuts are loose

Or a wheel/tyre could be elliptical. This should have been picked up by the balancing test but I guess it's possible for a wheel to be balanced but elliptical. You could check this by jacking the wheels up and spinning them by hand, looking for any high/flat spots.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This could even be possible with new tires? They have about 1200 miles on them now, but have been doing this since day 1.

Comment: You're welcome !  It could happen on nw tyres - if it's the wheel nuts thing then that's not their problem really and nothing to do with the tyres, but if the tyres are out of shape then that's definitely a case of taking them back and 'explaining'. It's also possible that the wheels have a "preferred" rotation on the wheel studs - eg if you took one off and moved it round 180 degrees that might help. that would imply something's up with the wheel itself though, maybe warped or something. The fact that it's only since new tyres is suspicious though.

Comment: Yeah that's the main reason I'm so confused is because this was never an issue until I replaced my worn tires. I will try some of the things you suggested, and if none of them seem to work I believe I will take them back and ask for something different.  Thanks again!